# How that helps to convert

Tags: bit-manipulation

There is not my front-end code that is converting X from int to short and save it in a binary stream

```
       write(x & 0xFF)
       write((x & 0xFFFF) >> 8 )
```

*(I am C++ back-end dev and not sure what the language this is.. looks like JS but there is no Int data type as I know.)*

I am don't understand how `x & 0xFF` and `(x & 0xFFFF) >> 8` helps to convert int to short. Can you explain?

Comment: That isn´t converting `int` to `short`, but `int` to 2 byte and hoping that the value of the `int` will fit in them (ie. hoping that no 3. or 4. byte necessary because they are 0).

Comment: How can you be a C++ developer and not know about bit manipulation? Not trying to troll, I'm just genuinely curious.

Comment: @JustSid it'd be a little worse for a *C* developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x & 0xFF` means "The least significant byte of x"

`(x & 0xFFFF) >> 8` means "The second least significant byte of x"

When written one after another, it represent `(short)x` (i.e the 2 least significant bytes of x) in little endian.